# How to adjust button width according to textlength or backgroud image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, tableview

I have a table view and a custom cell which has a button.According to my need I sometime set

1.Title of Button

or

2.Background image without title

on runtime.The problem is my button size specifically width is not changing according to textlength of title or according to background image size.I have tried **sizeToFit** and **cell.btnChat.sizeThatFits(backgroundimage.size)** but it does'nt reflect any change.

The "button" condition is for set title and image to set background image.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            if blockChatForLogin{
                if (chatRespones[indexPath.row].type == "text"){
                    //Adding rows in table
//                    let cell:ChatResponseController = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatResponseCell") as! ChatResponseController
                    let cell:CustLabelCell = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomLabelCell") as! CustLabelCell
                    cell.lblTextResponse.text = chatRespones[indexPath.row].value
                    cell.lblTextResponse.layer.masksToBounds=true
                    cell.lblTextResponse.layer.cornerRadius=5
                    return cell
                }
                else if (chatRespones[indexPath.row].type == "button"){
                    //Adding rows in table
                    let cell:CustButtonCell = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomButtonCell") as! CustButtonCell
                    cell.btnChat.setTitle(chatRespones[indexPath.row].value,for: .normal)
                    cell.btnChat.layer.masksToBounds=true
                    cell.btnChat.layer.cornerRadius=5
                    cell.btnChat.layer.borderWidth=2
                    cell.btnChat.layer.borderColor=UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.61, blue:0.49 ,alpha:1.0).cgColor
                    cell.delegete = self
                    return cell
                }
                else if (chatRespones[indexPath.row].type == "image"){
                    //Adding rows in table
//                    let cell:ChatButtonController = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatButtonCell") as! ChatButtonController
                    let cell:CustButtonCell = self.tbChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomButtonCell") as! CustButtonCell

                    if   let image: UIImage = UIImage(named:"\(chatRespones[indexPath.row].value.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "")).jpg")
                    {
                        cell.btnChat.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                        cell.btnChat.setTitle("",for: .normal)
                        cell.btnChat.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


                    }
                    else{
                        cell.btnChat.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                        cell.btnChat.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
                        cell.btnChat.setTitle("Error: Image Missing with name \(chatRespones[indexPath.row].value)",for: .normal)
                    }
                    cell.btnChat.layer.masksToBounds=true
                    cell.btnChat.layer.cornerRadius=5
                    cell.btnChat.layer.borderWidth=2
                    cell.btnChat.layer.borderColor=UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.61, blue:0.49 ,alpha:1.0).cgColor
                    cell.delegete = self
                    return cell
                }
            }
        default:
            print("No case")
        }

    }
```

Comment: show your code where u setting width according to textlength

Comment: Do not give a fixed width of the button in storyBoard, It adjusts self according to text.

Comment: In case of title you should first count the chara or text in your label and in case of uiimageview get the height and width of Image and then set dynamically buttonview height and width according to you text and imageview.

Comment: I tried by removing constant width and now its adjusting button size but content are too close.

Comment: There are problems with constraints. You have to setup them in the way when button will be flexible. Share screenshot of your cell with constraints so we could help you

Answer (score 0):

After you set the text of the cell, you can do this:

```
cell.textLabel.intrinsicContentWidth
```

To get the required width of the text, you can then create the frame of the view using the retrieved size as the width. Be careful if you have any fixed widths set in your storyboard or something, so it might be best to create your textLabel programmatically as well.